# Documents app hangs on file browser. How to export it's files w/o jailbreak?

Tags: ios, applications, filesystem

I used Documents app by Readdle, but now when I open it, it shows me the last document I was reading. When I try to switch back to file browser, it hangs, and I can't press anything. The question is how can I save my files and reinstall the app? Currently it has no updates on App Store.

I tried to use ifunbox and iTunes, but i can only see the "Inbox" folder which is empty.
Device is not jailbroken.

PS. This probably happens because the document's name contains unsupported characters.

Comment: I have the same problem. I submitted the diagnostic report to readdle. Still waiting for solution though.

Comment: I already reinstalled the app. It is caused by one book and not by it's name. Now i have only this book in Documents app. If i close the book, i have to wait ~25 seconds till file browser unfreezes. I have also sent an email to Readdle with the link on this question.